# Calculating multilingual string length in C# for storage in an Oracle VARCHAR2 field

Tags: c#, string, oracle, multilingual

I need to be able to store strings in an Oracle database.  The strings are of varying lengths, and some of them can be huge (ie: >10000 characters).

95% of the time, the string will be <=2000 characters (or so)
Only 5% of the time will the string exceed that limit.

Normally I'd just create a CLOB and stuff all the strings in there, however retrieval of a large number of records with a string stored in a CLOB is **dramatically** slower than using a VARCHAR2 field.

My solution is to have two fields within this table:

- TEXT_CONTENT VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
- TEXT_CONTENT_OVERFLOW CLOB

When the string is less than 4000 characters, I store it all in the TEXT_CONTENT field and leave the TEXT_CONTENT_OVERFLOW null.  If the string is over 4000 characters, I store the first 4000 in the VARCHAR2, and the remainder in the CLOB.

Performance tests with the ORM I'm using show this runs an order of magnitude faster than just using a CLOB.

And now my question..

I need to store a variety of languages in these fields - English, French, Korean, Chinese, etc.

I want to be able to store as much as possible in the VARCHAR2, but I need to know exactly how many bytes a string holds.

If its a string of English characters, I know I can fit 4000 characters in that VARCHAR2.  If its a string of all French characters, I know I can fit a max of 2000 characters because the French chars actually require 2 bytes of storage... And so on for other languages.

What I need to figure out is how to calculate the actual byte length of a C# string, such that I can perform an appropriate **string.Substring** call.

Comment: What is the text encoding in the database? Hint: this is the key. Count bytes /after/ converting to the target encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the database encoding is UTF8 (it's configurable, IIRC), then

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringValue).Length
```

should be a valid count. You might need to normalize to a "canonical form". .NET has methods for that too, but which canonical form is appropriate will have to come from the Oracle documentation.

Comment: Just what I was looking for!  UTF8.GetBytes("aaaa").Length returns 4.  UTF8.GetBytes("éééé").Length returns 8.  Now I just need to figure out how to perform a byte based "substring" call on a string that can contain French and English chars to make sure I don't inadvertently cut-off a multibyte character - but at least I'm now on the right track!

Comment: Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo.gettextelementenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx too